# is there anyway to pre-populate a slug field from the form fields in the template with django?

Tags: django, django-forms

Good day.
I have the following slug field in my admin.py:

```
prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
```

and in my forms.py:

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
        model = Book

        fields = [

            'username',
            'book',
            'slug',
            'password1',
            'password2',
        ]
```

and in my template:

```
    <from method=post action=''>
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.py }}
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: `prepopulated_fields` is related just to the admin interface - if you want to do it in a custom view, you have to do it yourself, via Javascript.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko thanks for the explanation. but will they both match ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @yedpodtrzitko in comments, `prepoluated_fields` only works for admin interface. If you want the same slugified field in your views, you have to slugify the fields yourself wherever you want it (in your views.py for example) by using the same `slugify` method that Django internally uses :

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

#wherever you want a slug:
mystring = 'a string to slugified'
slugified_string = slugify(mystring) #will output a-string-to-slugified
```